# How to generate a unique id in php that will never ever be repeated

Tags: php

Is there anyway to generate a uniqueid in php that will never ever be repeated. I know uniqid(); but i need something with about 8 characters that will never ever have a chance of being repeated.

Regards,
Jarrod

Comment: "that will never ever have a chance of being repeated" --- it's impossible. For that you need a value of infinite length.

Comment: How likely is uniqid() ever gonna have the same value

Comment: If you're putting the unique ID in a database, before INSERT, check if that ID already exists and if it does just generate a new one.

Comment: refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php, uniqid() doesn't guarantee absolute unique value.

Comment: The likelyhood is comprised of number of total combinations + the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)

Comment: 8 characters = 2^64 combinations, so after that many have been generated **any** scheme will lead to repeats.  Perhaps you should edit your question to tell us why you need the number and we might be able to help.

Comment: I used timestamp as unique id in my applications without any problems so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try something like this:

whenever you generate a insert query then its give you a serial id (auto-incremented). then you'll add 100000*5(+'your_auto-incremented_id'). this value always be unique.

I hope this logic will help you :)

Comment: That helps. I am gonna try checking if code is already in there just to use uniqid. It generates a code like a site im trying to clone.